# Как просуммировать все элементы коллекции? Ошибка компиляции: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer

Tags: java, arraylist, generics

Есть коллекция

```
ArrayList costs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Я хочу найти сумму всех ее элементов, для этого я написал вот что:

```
public Integer getCosts() {
    Integer temp = 0;
    for (Integer i : costs) {
        temp += i;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Но компилятор жалуется мне на `Integer i` ссылаясь на то, что он ждет `Object`, а я ему подсовываю `Integer`, но почему он так требует?

> ```
> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer
>     for (Integer i : costs) {
>                      ^
> ```

Лично видел в интернете, что подсовывают сюда различные типы, как мне исправить это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не:

```
ArrayList costs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

А:

```
ArrayList<Integer> costs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Нужно подсказывать компилятору с каким типом будет генерик

Comment: а в каких случаях пишут `new ArrayList<Integer>();`?

Comment: @ВладиславЖерихов, насколько я помню, до java7 нужно было с правой стороны писать тип, иначе компилятор ругался :)